# Does gles20.glCopyTexImage2D work in android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I was new to opengl es, So I use the sample code "HelloEffect" in android4.1 to do some tests. I use the function below to do render. if the "glCopyTexImage2D" function not been call at the end of renderTexture, then I can  re-render the texture correctly, but if the glCopyTexImage2D function is used, then the second time I call renderTexture,  GLToolbox.checkGlError("glViewport") will throw exceptions.

```
 public void renderTexture(int texId, int savetexture) {
    if(savetexture == 2)
        texId = mCaptureTexture[0];

    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, mViewWidth, mViewHeight);
    GLToolbox.checkGlError("glViewport");

    // Disable blending
    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);

    // Set the vertex attributes
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTexCoordHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            0, mTexVertices);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPosCoordHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            0, mPosVertices);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPosCoordHandle);
    GLToolbox.checkGlError("vertex attribute setup");

    // Set the input texture
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLToolbox.checkGlError("glActiveTexture");
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
    GLToolbox.checkGlError("glBindTexture");
    GLES20.glUniform1i(mTexSamplerHandle, 0);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(mEffectTypeHandle, 1);

    // Draw
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

     if(savetexture == 1)
        GLES20.glCopyTexImage2D(mCaptureTexture[0], 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, 0, 0, mTexWidth, mTexHeight, 0); 
    return;
}    

//main workflow

renderTexture(srctexture, 0);
renderTexture(srctexture, 0);
//+above steps is work normal.

renderTexture(srctexture, 1);
renderTexture(srctexture, 2);
//in above steps, when call  renderTexture(srctexture, 2)   
//gLToolbox.checkGlError ("glViewport")will throw exception
```

my purpose to do this is that I will keep a copy of framebuffer's  color buffer, as I have done some post-processing work to the texId texture, so it will save time if I don't have to do the post-processing work again.
I wonder if I have omit some critical steps above, or opengl es 2.0 is not prefect for this work
best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

Your usage and interpretation of `checkGLError` is likely to be incorrect: OpenGL error reporting is **stateful**, *the error flag isn't reset until you actually check it*.

Most likely, the line

```
GLES20.glCopyTexImage2D(...);
```

is the one setting the error flag. You just don't check (and reset) it until after the next call to `glViewPort`.

...

On to the actual problem: if you could post your exact error message, we could provide further assistance as to what is wrong at that line. It looks like your parameters are specified incorrectly, it should probably be something like

```
GLES20.glBindTexture( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mCaptureTexture[0] );
GLES20.glCopyTexImage2D( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, ... );
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply , I misunderstand the first parameter of "GLenum target"  in function glCopyTexImage2D. Thank you again